# Regex to replace character between square brackets, but not between parenthesis

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, regex-lookarounds

I have a list of Markdown links that look like this:

```
[filename-with-some-words](/001-folder/filename-with-some-words.md)
[title-with-other-words](/001-folder/title-with-other-words.md)
[other-words](/001-folder/other-words.md)
```

I want to replace the `-` that occur between square brackets `[]`, but not those that occur between parenthesis `()` such that my final result would look like:

```
[filename with some words](/001-folder/filename-with-some-words.md)
[title with other words](/001-folder/title-with-other-words.md)
[other words](/001-folder/other-words.md)
```

I can match *all* text between brackets with `(?<=\[).+?(?=\])`, but how do I match only the dash `-`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)[^][-]*\K-(?=[^][]*])
```

Replace with a space. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IE1VrN/1).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)` - either the end of the previous successful match or `[`
- `[^][-]*` - any 0+ chars other than `]`, `[` and `-`
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far from the whole match memory buffer
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?=[^][]*])` - that is followed with 0+ non-bracket chars till a `]` char.